# Adding custom fields to a User model using server side functionality while leveraging Devise for initial authentication

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, model

I'm using Devise for authentication in a Rails 5 web app. My user registration views are all devise-generated, and I added a few fields to a form to be able to dynamically generate PGP keys on the front-end. I created a database migration for these extra key fields, and they are saving properly. Now I'm trying to add some fields that I create on the server side that aren't user input fields.

Here is my registration controller:

```
class User::RegistrationsController < Devise::RegistrationsController
  before_action :sign_up_params, only: [:create]
  # before_action :configure_account_update_params, only: [:update]

  def show
    @user = User.find(params[:id])

  end

  private
  def sign_up_params
    params.require(:user).permit(
        :handle,
        :pin,
        :email,
        :password,
        :password_confirmation,
        :pgp_privatekey,
        :pgp_publickey
    )
  end
end
```

Now, what I'm trying to figure out is the 'best' way to save fields that aren't a result of user input (say, for example, a lat/long estimate based on their IP address, or something like a bitcoin address that is entirely generated on the server side). I feel like this might be most appropriately done in my controller during the initial call to the registration controller, perhaps done when the registration initially occurs. But since it isn't user driven, I'm not sure where in my controller it makes sense to add this logic.

I implemented a method in my User model called "generate_bitcoin_keypair" and I want to save the generated fields in the correct user record in the db but I'm trying to understand whether I should just add this in my initial registration code by extending the base Devise functionality with a super() call and a resource block, or whether it makes sense to put this elsewhere? Obviously now that the method is defined in my User.rb model code, I can call it in my controller, but I'm just trying to understand whether this is the best, most concise way to do what I'm trying to accomplish.

Here is my User model:

```
require 'bitcoin'
class User < ApplicationRecord
  # Include default devise modules. Others available are:
  # :confirmable, :lockable, :timeoutable, :trackable and :omniauthable
  devise :database_authenticatable, :registerable,
         :recoverable, :rememberable, :validatable

  def self.generate_bitcoin_keypair
    key = Bitcoin::Key.generate()
    {:btc_addr => key.addr, :btc_privkey => key.priv}
  end
end
```

hsould I implement a create method in my registration controller that basically calls the User model's generate_bitcoin_keypair code, and then saves it to the respective user (based on the session[:id]) ?

I'm trying to understand the best way to accomplish this, and if my question is at all unclear then please let me know.

I'm thinking something like this might work:

```
  def create
    super do
      btcdata = User.generate_bitcoin_keypair()
      resource.btc_address = btcdata.btc_addr
      resource.btc_privatekey = btcdata.btc_privkey
      resource.save
    end
  end
```

in my registration_controller.rb, but since the user record has already been created and saved in the database, I'm thinking maybe it should be in something like the edit method rather than the create method, and I'm not entirely clear on where exactly the logic should sit.

Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

I would not put it in the controller. Like you mentioned, this is not user driven behavior. I think this is behavior inherent to the creation of a new user. Therefore, I would leave the logic to generate bitcoin key-pairs in the `User` model and call it in an `ActiveRecord` [callback](https://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Callbacks.html)

```rb
require 'bitcoin'
class User < ApplicationRecord
  devise :database_authenticatable, :registerable,
         :recoverable, :rememberable, :validatable

  before_create :generate_bitcoin_keypair

  def generate_bitcoin_keypair
    key = Bitcoin::Key.generate()
    self.btc_address = key.addr
    self.btc_privatekey = key.priv
  end
end
```

This will generate the bitcoin key-pair and assign the attributes to the User record before it is created in the database.

Comment: I like this approach too. Why should the devise controller be responsible for creating these keys, and persisting them?

Comment: One problem with this code is that you are just creating local variables in your `generate_bitcoin_keypair` method. You have to use `self.btc_address = key.addr`.

Answer (score 0):

You can tap into the flow of the `Devise::RegistrationsController#create` before the record is saved by redefining [`#build_resource`](https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/blob/e3a00b27d19ba995891d7dd92394fe2900a789c2/app/controllers/devise/registrations_controller.rb#L99):

```
class User::RegistrationsController < Devise::RegistrationsController
  protected
  def build_resource(hash = {})
    super
    self.resource.ip_address = request.remote_ip
  end
end
```

This method is where Devise binds the params and session information to the resource being created.

Devise also provides `#update_resource` where you can tap into the `#update` method. I would encourage you to read through [the source](https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/blob/master/app/controllers/devise/registrations_controller.rb) - it can be a bit daunting at first due to the crazy level of configurability but provides tons of hooks.

To allow additional parameters its a better idea to [append the Devise param sanitizer](https://github.com/plataformatec/devise#strong-parameters) instead of re-implementing the whole thing, as this will *just work* if you decide to add more Devise modules in the future.

```
class User::RegistrationsController < Devise::RegistrationsController
  # ...
  def configure_permitted_parameters
     #
    devise_parameter_sanitizer.permit(:sign_up, keys: [:handle])
  end
end
```

Note that you should NOT allow parameters that should not be coming from the request parameters such as `pgp_privatekey` and `pgp_publickey` as it makes it trivial for a malicious user to spoof your controller with cURL. This applies to Rails as a whole and is the whole reason we have strong parameters.

That said you should be placing as much as possible of the business logic in the model where it belongs. For example the generation of the bitcoin keypair can be done in the model as well as [geolocation from an IP](https://github.com/alexreisner/geocoder#basic-search). Models are much easier to test than controllers.

```
# Example uses the Geocoder gem
require 'bitcoin'
class User < ApplicationRecord
  # Omit this if you have a database column for ip_address
  attr_accessor :ip_address 
  devise :database_authenticatable, :registerable,
         :recoverable, :rememberable, :validatable
  before_create :generate_bitcoin_keypair!
  before_create :geocode_from_ip!, if: :can_be_geocoded?

  protected

  def generate_bitcoin_keypair!
    Bitcoin::Key.generate.tap do |key|
      self.btc_address = key.addr
      self.btc_privatekey = key.priv
    end
  end

  def geocode_from_ip!
    results = Geocoder.search(self.ip_address)
    self.coordinates = results.first.coordinates if results.any?
  end

  def can_be_geocoded?
    ip_address.present?
  end
end
```